# Lagom: Read Side Processor vs Broker Api to build read model

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, lagom

Reading lagom documentation, we can build read side with both read side processor and message broker api.

What are advantages to use one over another?

(Let's take into account general ReadSide support (not Cassandra and Jdbc which implement event offset tracking).

Prototyping some application, I've noticed that Read Side Processor has higher latency between events persistence into event log and read model update than Broker Api.

Answer (score 0):

> Prototyping some application, I've noticed that Read Side Processor
>   has higher latency between events persistence into event log and read
>   model update than Broker Api.

This is the eventual consistency delay. You can change this with a setting in your application.conf:

```
cassandra-query-journal.eventual-consistency-delay = 1s
```

You have to decide what is necessary for your application. You can set this to zero, but it is rarely necessary.